# What does "prod issues" mean in computer science and software engineering?

Tags: meaning, software, software-bugs

> DevOps engineers are those who are good at debugging, troubleshooting, analyzing **prod issues** and providing solutions. Who have good hands on technologies like unix shell scripting, perl, SQL etc.
>
> Software engineering is typically involved in designing, writing code and fixing the bugs reported

What "prod issues" means here? I have google it but still confused.

Comment: production issues-  issues with production software, i.e., software that has been released to or is in use by the public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Prod" in this case is a common abbreviation for *production*. A production system is one used to run an organisation's main servers or infrastructure. A collection of systems that share a common purpose may be referred to collectively as an *environment*. For example, a *production environment* might be made up of many production systems (servers).

In my organisation, we have environments for production, dev (*development*, used to develop new software), sandbox (used for experimentation), and test (used for QA and validation).

Many organisations restrict who can access each environment. Production environments are  the most restricted of all, as they are usually critical to an organisation's core operations.